# Django 1.8 error: No database fixture specified

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-database

I was using an `sqlite` database and after applying `python manage.py dumpdata` I added the new `postgresql` database settings in `settings.py`

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'music',                      
    'USER': '**',
    'PASSWORD': '****',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT': '5432',
    }
  }
```

But when I try to load the data into the new `postgresql` database I get the following error

```
C:\Users\Saket\musicalguru>python manage.py loaddata
usage: manage.py loaddata [-h] [--version] [-v {0,1,2,3}]
                      [--settings SETTINGS] [--pythonpath PYTHONPATH]
                      [--traceback] [--no-color] [--database DATABASE]
                      [--app APP_LABEL] [--ignorenonexistent]
                      fixture [fixture ...]
manage.py loaddata: error: No database fixture specified. Please provide the  path of at least one fixture in the command line.
```

Can't understand what the error is. I already have data in my `sqlite` database so I need the new data in the `postgresql` database too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you show how you did the data dump? If you look at the [`dumpdata` docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata-app-label-app-label-app-label-model), you'll see that it:

> Outputs to standard output all data in the database associated with the named application(s).

And:

> By default, `dumpdata` will format its output in JSON

Now, if you take a look at your error, you'll see that you are missing a database fixture. The [`loaddata` docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#loaddata-fixture-fixture) tells what a fixture is and where Django will look for fixtures:

> A fixture is a collection of files that contain the serialized contents of the database. Each fixture has a unique name, and the files that comprise the fixture can be distributed over multiple directories, in multiple applications.
>
> Django will search in three locations for fixtures:
>
> 1. In the `fixtures` directory of every installed application
> 2. In any directory named in the `FIXTURE_DIRS` setting
> 3. In the literal path named by the fixture

So, the file that you dump your data to can be used:

```
./manage.py dumpdata ... > mydata.json
./manage.py loaddata mydata.json
```

Comment: Well running `manage.py dumpdata > mydata.json` creates a file with only  a list of available django sub-commands. There is no data in it. And running `manage.py loaddata mydata.json` just returns the same list on the command line. Earlier running `python manage.py dumpdata` at least returned a scrambled list of all the data in the database. What could be the issue?

Comment: Weird, the only time I've seen the list of `manage.py`'s subcommands is if I run it w/o a subcommand or if I run it w/ `--help`. Run it exactly as you did when it 'worked', but put `> mydata.json` after.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell `loaddata` which file to load if it is not in app `fixtures` directory:

```
python manage.py loaddata file/path/of/dumbdata.json
```

Either you move your dumped data in `fixtures` directory of app or specify file manually as I stated above. Read move about `loaddata` command [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#loaddata-fixture-fixture).